# Disable dates in Protoplasm DatePicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, prototype

I am using the ProtoPlasm Datepicker in one of my apps, now I want to disable all the dates earlier than today.

I used the following code:

```
Protoplasm.use('datepicker').transform('input[type="text"].xyz_datepicker', {dateFormat: 'MM/dd/yyyy'});
```

But I'm still unable to do it. Any help?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that is restricting the date range.  What have you tried?

Comment: That's what I am asking. How to disable the dates earlier than today. And by the way I have tried the minDate option for the date-picker. But no positive results yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by adding the following line of code to my js file:

```
Protoplasm.use('datepicker').transform('input.datepicker', { 'minDate' : '1/1/2016' })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Protoplasm; however, according to their doc, you should be able to do this:

```
Protoplasm.use('datepicker')
    .transform('input.datepicker', { 'minDate' : '1/1/2016' })
```

Ref. http://jongsma.org/software/protoplasm/control/datepicker

However, I don't recommend this approach.  I recommend just using standard jQuery UI as outlined https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max